# How to use upn instead of DN for openLdap Authentication

Tags: java, authentication, active-directory, openldap

I am trying to authenticate against an openldap server from Java .

I tried setting my LDAPContext SECURITY_PRINCIPAL to the DN and it works.

```
    Hashtable<Object, Object> env = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapHost);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=admin,ou=People,dc=maxcrc,dc=com");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    env.put("java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary","objectSID");

    if (sslAuth) {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", sslKeyStore);
        env.put(DirContext.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
        // System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","ssl");
    }
    LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
    return ctx;
}
```

What i am trying now is to authenticate using UserPrincipalName,Similar to AD authentication,it gives INVALID DN error.

```
    Hashtable<Object, Object> env = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapHost);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "admin@people.maxcrc.com");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    env.put("java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary","objectSID");

    if (sslAuth) {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", sslKeyStore);
        env.put(DirContext.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
        // System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","ssl");
    }
    LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
    return ctx;
}
```

How can i configure the openldap settings to allow authentication using UPN

Comment: I've never used any of the Java libraries for AD, but I know AD. You could search for the user account by UPN and grab the DN, then use that DN to authenticate.